# 1px border around uneven amount of divs

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to solve an issue which has plagued me for so long. I'm attempting to create the following with css:

https://gyazo.com/c8ae39ebc4795027ba7c1067a08d3420

There is an uneven amount of divs which I currently have styled like so:

```
.box{
    background-color: grey;
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

I am attempting to re-style the divs in the middle using nth-child but it's making the divs go into weird orders and just feels really messy. Is there an easier way?

Codepen for roughly what I'm trying to do:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RrqNzM

Thanks.

Comment: can you post the rest of you code. Preferably in something like jsfiddle or codepen.

Comment: please put your code in jsfiddle

Comment: Do you mean you want the divs to centre align *inside* the wrapper div?

Comment: I've added a codepen above which shows roughly what I'd like to do. But I'm unable to find an easy way to style the divs so there is only a 1px border around them all.

Comment: is it possible to use js..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no standard way to do this, a simple trick is to use a `border` only on the right and bottom of the `.box` and only top and left on the wrapping element. That way, you give the illusion that the borders collapse.

```css
.box,
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.box {
  border-top: none;
  border-left: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 33.33333333%;
  float: left;
  height: 45px;
}
.wrapper {
  border-right: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, shame there's no standard way of achieving this!

Answer (score 1):

Check here different approach for same solution
fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/anilram25/rztfv00f/

```
<div class="main-div">
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

and css

```
html, body{
    margin: 0;
}

*{
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.main-div{
  border-top:5px solid #CD4431;
  border-bottom:5px solid #CD4431;
  background-color:#1B1B1C;
  padding-bottom:1px;
  padding-left:1px;
}
.box{
    background-color: #282828;
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
    margin-right: -1px ;
  margin-bottom: -1px ;
  height: 50px;
}
.clearfix{

  clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **keep the border of the container** to show....

(1) Remove the left and top borders of the children:

```
div.wrap > div { border: 1px solid #666; border-left: none; border-top: none; }
```

(2) Use `nth-child(3n)` to remove the right border of every third child div:

```
div.wrap > div:nth-child(3n) { border-right: none; }
```

(3) Then for the last div, remove the bottom border:

```
div.wrap > div:nth-last-child(-n+1) { border-bottom: none; }
```

**Note:** If you have more than seven children, then for every extra child increase the `m` in `(-n+m)`. e.g. if you have eight children, it would be `(-n+2)` and for nine children `(-n+3)`.

**Snippet:**

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; padding:0; margin:0; }
div.wrap {
 width: 75vw; margin: 16px; overflow: hidden; 
 border: 1px solid #666; 
 /*border-top: 5px solid darkorange; border-bottom: 5px solid darkorange;*/
}
div.wrap > div {
 width: 33.3333%;  height: 48px; float: left; 
 line-height: 48px; padding: 0px 8px; overflow: hidden;
 border: 1px solid #666; border-left: none; border-top: none;
}
div.wrap > div:nth-child(3n) { border-right: none; }
div.wrap > div:nth-last-child(-n+1) { border-bottom: none; }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
 <div>Lorem ipsum</div><div>Lorem ipsum</div><div>Lorem ipsum</div>
 <div>Lorem ipsum</div><div>Lorem ipsum</div><div>Lorem ipsum</div>
 <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, is there any way I could edit the nth-child part to work if I didn't know how many divs there would be? Right now I have three sections of divs, one with 7, one with 8 and one with 4. The 7 one looks fine based on your snippet but 8 and 4 are missing borders in some places.

Comment: Nopes. You need to handcraft it.

Comment: What about for mobile and tablet, the position of the divs goes all weird.

Comment: @SpencerHaizel: I do not see any problems with mobile/tablet sizes. https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/984aecg3/ works just fine.